# How to construct a line graph from a time series table in Neo4j using Cypher?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to construct a line graph from a time series table in Neo4j using Cypher?

For example:

Here is a table

```
id | event    | timestamp
----------------------
1  | event1   | 10:00 AM
1  | event2   | 10:15 AM
1  | event3   | 10:30 AM
.  |   .      |   .
.  |   .      |   .
.  |   .      |   .
1  | event100 | 8:00 PM

2  | event25  | 10:10 AM
2  | event30  | 10:20 AM
2  | event150 | 11:20 AM
.  |   .      |   .
.  |   .      |   .
.  |   .      |   .
```

so I want to group the events by `id` and order them according to timestamp and construct the graph like this for each group

```
event1 -> event2 -> ... -> event100
```

and

```
event25 -> event30 -> event150 -> ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're happy adding the [APOC plugin](https://neo4j.com/developer/neo4j-apoc/) to your database, what you're describing is a linked list that can be created using `apoc.nodes.link`.

Some example data:

```
MERGE (e1: Event { id: 1, event: 'Event1', timestamp: localdatetime('20200323T10:00:00') })
MERGE (e2: Event { id: 1, event: 'Event3', timestamp: localdatetime('20200323T10:20:00') })
MERGE (e3: Event { id: 1, event: 'Event2', timestamp: localdatetime('20200323T10:05:00') })
MERGE (e4: Event { id: 2, event: 'Event5', timestamp: localdatetime('20200323T10:08:00') })
MERGE (e5: Event { id: 2, event: 'Event4', timestamp: localdatetime('20200323T10:00:00') })
```

Then we can group, sort and create the linked lists:

```
MATCH (e: Event)
WITH e ORDER BY e.timestamp
WITH e.id as id, collect(e) as nodes
CALL apoc.nodes.link(nodes, 'PRECEDES')
RETURN nodes
```

[image]